# NullPointerException while analyzing a project in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, eclipse-mars

I am getting a "Synchronization issues have encountered a problem" along with a NullPointerException while analyzing a project in SonarQube 6.2. 
I am using Eclipse Mars 4.5.2 and I tried using SonarLint but didnt find it very useful because it didnt show me SonarQube Issues view and all the errors were not listed in there. So, I instead downloaded the SonarQube plugin (http://downloads.sonarsource.com/eclipse/eclipse/)

I see the below issues in the access.log (in SonarQube directory) -

```
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2017:11:40:50 -0500] "GET /api/resources?resource=ffsUser%3AffsUser&verbose=false& HTTP/1.1" 200 237 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.3.6 (java 1.5)" "AVpCmoaydo39Zfz7AAAv"
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2017:11:40:50 -0500] "GET /api/issues/search?componentRoots=ffsUser:ffsUser&pageIndex=1&pageSize=-1&resolved=false HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Java/1.8.0_45" "AVpCmoaydo39Zfz7AAAw"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not surprising that you're encountering problems attempting to run the old Eclipse plugin against a current version of SonarQube. There are reasons that plugin as abandoned.

Your best bet would be to try again with SonarLint, which is designed to help you keep new code clean and to clean up the code you're already working on anyway

Comment: In SonarLint, I cannot see all the errors categorised properly (minor, major, critical etc.) It only shows me .js errors and if I open a particular java file in eclipse then it shows the errors in that java file. I want to be able to see all the errors in all the java files.

Comment: Just to let you know, I can see the java errors in the projects on my local SonarQube server (http://localhost:9000) but in my eclipse I am not able to see those errors using SonarLint according to categories. 
When I open that particular java file in eclipse then it shows errors in "Sonar on the fly" view. Any suggestions on how can I analyze the whole project and see all the existing errors in all the files, please?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're experiencing. This might be better at the [SonarLint Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/sonarlint)